# How to find similar row value and consider count duplicate values between two CSV files

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 csv file formatted like below:

**csv A**

```
Tweet1,pos
Tweet2,neg
Tweet2,neg
```

**csv B**

```
Tweet2,neg
Tweet2,neg
Tweet2,pos
```

I would like to find the number of similarity between raws

I tried this but this it seams gives the differences

```
def compare( fileA, fileB ):
    a_file = open(fileA, 'r')
    a_data = a_file.read()
    a_file.close()

    b_file = open(fileB, 'r')
    b_data = b_file.read()
    b_file.close()

    # compare the contents
    a_set = set(a_data.split(','))
    b_set = set(b_data.split(','))

    return list(a_set.intersection(b_set))

print compare('f.csv', 'full-corpus.csv')
```

The output should be 1

Comment: your current code is splitting the entire file contents with a comma. what you need to do is to compare lines. so try splitting with a '\n' instead of a ','

Comment: @PrateekDewan why the intersection in 'list(a_set.intersection(b_set))' does not count the duplicates values for example **Tweet2,neg** occurred two times in csv A and two times in csv B, why len consider that one time.

Comment: It's not `len`.  Sets only contain unique values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This do the trick, you just need to import class counter from collection then open every file as a list.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
a_list = []
with open('1.csv', 'Ur') as a_file:
    for line in csv.reader(a_file):
        a_list.append(line[0]+' '+line[1])
print a_list

b_list = []
with open('2.csv', 'Ur') as b_file:
    for line in csv.reader(b_file):
        b_list.append(line[0]+' '+line[1])
print b_list
counterA = Counter(a_list)
counterB = Counter(b_list)
counterSum = counterB & counterA
print counterA
print counterB
print counterB & counterA
print sum(counterSum.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `return len(a_set & b_set)`.  `&` is the operator to find elements present in all sets, and the `len` will be the number of elements that are present in all sets

Comment: I understand that len, but to be sure I returned the list as well and always get empty value in the returned list like this ['', 'Tweet2,neg'] for both intersection and &

Comment: why the & does not count the duplicates values for example Tweet2,neg occurred two times in csv A and two times in csv B, why len consider that one time.

Comment: Because you used sets.  It only keeps the unique lines so there will be only 1 occurrence in both sets.

Comment: @Alsphere that is a harder problem.  You could use dictionaries and count duplicates, then compare their counts.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I will edit the question to count duplicates, you can post your solution to accept it to be reference for others.